# How to set chunk size when using pathos ProcessingPool's map?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

I'm running into inefficient parallelisation with Pathos' `ProcessingPool.map()` function: Towards the end of the processing, a single slow running worker processes the last tasks in the list sequentially while other workers are idle. I think this is due to "chunking" of the task list.

When using Python's own `multiprocessing.Pool` I can resolve this by forcing `chunksize=1` when calling `map`. However, this argument is not supported by Pathos, and the source code suggests this may be an oversight or a todo on the developers' side:

```
return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
```

(from Pathos' `multiprocessing.py`, line 137)

I'd like to keep Pathos because of it's ability to work with lamdbas.

Is there any way to get chunk size running in Pathos? Is there a workaround using one of Patho's other poorly documented pool implementations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` developer.  It's not an oversight... you can't use `chunksize` when using `pathos.pools.ProcessingPool`.  The reason this was done, was that I wanted to have the `map` functions have the same interface as python's `map`... and to do that, based on the `multiprocessing` implementation, I either had to choose to make `chunksize` a keyword, or to allow `*args` and `**kwds`.  So I choose the latter.

If you want to use `chunksize`, there is `_ProcessPool`, which retains the original `multiprocessing.Pool` interface, but has augmented serialization.

```
>>> import pathos
>>> p = pathos.pools._ProcessPool() 
>>> p.map(lambda x:x*x, range(4), chunksize=10)
[0, 1, 4, 9]
>>>
```

I'm sorry you feel the documentation is lacking.  The code is primarily composed of a fork of `multiprocessing` from the python standard library... and I didn't change the documentation where the functionality has been reproduced.  For example, here I am recycling the STL docs, as the functionality is the same:

```
>>> p = pathos.pools._ProcessPool()
>>> print(p.map.__doc__)

        Equivalent of `map()` builtin

>>> p = multiprocessing.Pool()
>>> print(p.map.__doc__)

        Equivalent of `map()` builtin
>>>
```

... and in the cases where I have modified functionality, I did write new docs:

```
>>> p = pathos.pools.ProcessPool()
>>> print(p.map.__doc__)
run a batch of jobs with a blocking and ordered map

Returns a list of results of applying the function f to the items of
the argument sequence(s). If more than one sequence is given, the
function is called with an argument list consisting of the corresponding
item of each sequence.

>>>
```

Admittedly, the docs could be better. Especially the docs coming from the STL could be improved upon.  Please feel free to add a ticket on GitHub, or even better, a PR to extend the docs.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed and incredibly quick answer, it works! I think a hint on `chunksize` would greatly improve the docs. There's no reference to it on pathos.readthedocs.io (at least not one retuned by the search). Or even a `map_with_chunksize` method in `Pool`, or a `chunk_size` param in the constructor? I understand you design choice here, but for my use case the parameter turns out to be quite essential.

Comment: Point taken about the docs.  In reality, my decision about the documentation was to flatly reuse what was in the STL unless I wrote new functionality (which honestly wasn't too much).  I wrote those docs probably a decade ago, but they could use revisiting.  I'll add a GitHub ticket to improve the docs.